# Can we Add an EBook kinda functionality to Telegram bots for viewing lengthy messages?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, telegram-bot

So, Currently if suppose I have an article of around 1500 words and I don't wanna use telegra.ph, neither I want to send two messages to send the complete article.

I want to send the complete article in one message.

So for that, Can we group two messages with two different id's and link them through Inline Buttons - Next and Previous.

The next button will open the second message, and previous will return to the first.

Is it possible, How can I do it if it is. And Do anyone has a better idea if it isn't.

I am creating a group solely for writers. As stories, novels, articles, are some Times quite lengthy I want readers that feasibility to read such long writeups without having to go to Telegra.ph or reading multiple messages. Instead an ebook format for the readers to read the next page or chapter by just clicking the "Next" Inline button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by adding "Next" InlineButton.

Read official documentation for the library you choose and examples there.

Comment: I am working In Telegraf Node Js Library. Will check out. Is it also possible, that if while sending a message if it's bigger than the selected words the bot will automatically convert the message into two pages after its sent.

Comment: automatically ? No, instead check the length of the string if its greater than telegrams default value add a function to split it  and add a inline button saying "Next Page ->"
add a callback function which intercepts when user click the button and make the bot edit the current message to second page

Comment: Thanks soo much. Instead of telegram's default value, can I set the value to be 500 words for the pages.